What happens at 1:13-1:15 in Frank Zappa's Sofa #1?
There seems to be a time signature change at that point. The rest of the song is clearly in 3/4, but it seems like there's a measure of 4/4 there that's at a slightly faster tempo--if you keep counting 3/4 through it, the first beat of the following measure of 3/4 comes a fraction of a second earlier than it should (as far as I can tell).
Hear it here:



I looked at a graphic representation of the chords and tempo here:
https://chordify.net/chords/frank-zappa-songs/sofa-no-1-chords
but it doesn't seem accurate.

It sounds to me like the 3 beat continues through both bars, the first bar has some syncopation which makes it sound odd and the second bar is a 4-notes-in-3-beats (analogous to a 2-beat triplet only putting more notes in the beats instead of fewer.)

This is a polyrhythm, where one or more measures are played with a different number of beats taking up the same amount of time. It's a fairly common technique, although 4-against-3, as in this example, is rare. It's much more commonly heard in the form of triplets, which are generally 3-against-2 (Star Wars Theme).
That's talking about the Western classical and pop traditions, however. Complex polyrhythms are common elsewhere around the world. In Indian classical music, you can sometimes hear mind-bending variations such as 11-against-7 or 5-against-9. 5-against-4 is popular in South American music (El Condor Pasa. You also hear it in older Hip Hop, and arguably in reggaeton). And in West African music, complex polyrhythms that are harder to describe are more the rule than the exception (Water Get No Enemy).
As for the slight time difference, that's probably a touch of rubato (expressive tempo variation), possibly unintentional (since the main beat doesn't continue through this measure, it would be easy to get a bit off), or intentional and for effect. Older recordings weren't typically recorded to a click beat the way modern recordings are, so rubato was a common technique (compare this question: What are name and other examples for the type of break/tempo change near the end of "Be our guest").

Knowing how tight Zappa's bands were, I'm willing to bet that the rubato was intentional.
